# Ubuntu 16.04 Dell Screen Tearing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed (from fresh) on my Dell Vostro 14, but I'm seeing screen tearing mainly on Google-chrome, but I think that's just because I use it the most. It only seems to happen on the 2nd monitor (HDMI), it doesn't happen on the laptop screen, nor the VGA screen. I've replaced the HDMI cable (and tried a different monitor). I'm not sure what information you need for my issue, but I believe it's an on-board intel graphics card.

If I move my mouse over the tearing then it goes away for a minute or two, but it always comes back.

[image: screen tearing]

Answer (score 4):

I used the most basic solution to fix screen tearing with the Intel iGPU (integrated Graphics Processing Unit).

With `sudo` powers edit/create the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` and copy in the following:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection
```

Save the file.

After making these changes you'll need to restart xserver either by logging in again or rebooting. The latter is always preferable for me.

---

**NOTE:** [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics) recommends putting the file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` which I've been using for a year. Both locations work.

Comment: It's actually in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf now. I actually had already tried this, still doing it!

Comment: @Farkie actually both locations work. I've updated the answer though to reflect the Ubuntu 16.04 way with a link to the Arch Linux way. If your problem persists check out the link for even more tips.

Comment: that made my dell fail to boot (ubuntu 20).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well, and what you need to do is to instal **Compizconfig settings manager**:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

then press **"Composite" on General** and make sure **Unredirect Fullscreen windows** is checked, as well as Detect refresh rate.

[image]
[image]

Then, open **"Workarounds"**. and enable the options **"Force complete redraw on initial damage" AND "Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint"**

[image]

*of course make sure both workarounds and composite as well as OpenGL are enabled*

Then, just suspend or reboot your PC, and it seems that there is no more screen tearing! I hope it helps you :)

*Please have a look here if you want more details* [http://www.howtoeverything.net/linux/issues/finally-no-more-tearing-anywhere-mate-desktop-and-compiz](http://www.howtoeverything.net/linux/issues/finally-no-more-tearing-anywhere-mate-desktop-and-compiz://)

Comment: All of these were already enabled :(

Comment: @Farkie try the other option they gave you on the website(the one for nvidia graphics card), im really sorry it didn't help:(

Comment: Heh no problem, just hoping something will solve it! I'll try the other one tomorrow :)

Comment: Did it work mate? I realy hope it did :)

Comment: I'm afraid not :( Starting to think I'll never find the solution! - I don't have a nvidia card, it's just an inbuilt intel graphics chip, though.

Comment: I won't give up yet, try one more thing. disable the option Unredirect Fullscreen Windows on composite, and leave everything as I said before. It worked for me on another pc so it might work for you